# Ruby on Rails generate ActiveRecord model with settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to create model by generating in terminal with command 
`rails generate model ...`

How can i set validation of uniqueness on one of column, and name of primary_key field using that command?
I found how could it be done by:
`rails g model model_name field_name1:type:uniq field_name2:type:primary_key...`

It sets for the table in database primary_key and uniqueness on certain fields with the migration. However i want to define settings for the ActiveRecord model which will be stored in "ModelName.rb" file in the "models" folder of my project.

For now i call the `ModelName.validates_uniqueness_of(:field_name)` method every time when I operate with records of model to prevent adding record with duplicate values on `:field_name1`

Comment: Configure your model to do the validation, instead of manually doing it. Refer [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Comment: As @Abhi said its outside the scope of that generator. They are designed to give you the barebones(scaffolding) to then change it to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validate helper `uniqueness: true` which validates the uniqueness of the attribute's value right before the object gets saved.

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :field_name1 uniqueness: true
end
```

And, as @Abhi pointed out for you, take a look at the [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) Documentation.